# Hexagon Complex Number Geometry

Tags: complex-numbers

The diagonals $AC$ and $CE$ of the regular hexagon ABCDEF are divided by the inner points M and
N, respectively, so that $AM/AC =CN/CE = r$. Determine $r$ if $B, M,$ and $N$ are collinear.

The process to do this by coordinates is very tedious. Does anyone know how to do this with the use of complex number geometry specifically?

Comment: Take the degenerate case of when M=N=center of the triangle. Done. You get the answer as 1.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the complex plane, let $\omega = e^{\pi/3}$ be an elementary sixth root of unity. We find that $\omega^2 = \omega - 1$.

Let $A = 1+\omega, B = \omega, C = 0, D = 1-\omega, E = 2-\omega, F = 2$. These six points form a regular hexagon.

Then $M = (1-r)A, N = rE$.

Let $X = M\bar N + N\bar B + B\bar M$, simplify to obtain $X = a(r) + b(r)\omega$ for some real values $a(r)$ and $b(r)$ depending on $r$.

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109196/show-that-three-complex-numbers-z-1-z-2-z-3-are-collinear-iff-operatorname) we find that $M, N, B$ are collinear iff $X$ is real, which is the case iff $b(r) = 0$. By solving that you should be done quickly.

Comment: Also, we can use determinants to do it easily.